# rails 4 ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I try to do a simple create using rails 4

my controller:

```
class AdsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @ad = Ad.new
  end

  def create
    @ad = Ad.new(params[:ad])    
    @ad.save
  end

  def show
    @ad = Ad.find(params[:id])
  end

  def index
    @ads = Ad.first(3)
  end


  private
  def ad_params    
    params.require(:ad).permit(:title, :price, :description)
  end
end
```

form:

```
<%= form_for @ad do |p| %>
  <p><%= p.text_field :title %></p>
  <p><%= p.text_field :price %></p>
  <p><%= p.text_area :description %></p>
  <p><%= p.submit %></p>
<% end %>
```

from my point of view it's ok but I got this error `ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError`
what I'm doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**

my problem was passing wrong value to new method in create action: the solution was to pass `ad_params` to it

Answer (score 41, accepted):

*I would suggest skipping to update so your code works*

Your problem is probably not in your controller, but your model:
Check to see your attributes are accessible with the follow tag

```
attr_accessible :title, :price, :description
```

Rails 4 does do it a little different from what I understand, this previous SO answer provided some good links:
[How is attr_accessible used in Rails 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17371334/how-is-attr-accessible-used-in-rails-4)

You need to use attr_accessible/Strong Params whenever you're accessing things from the database.

**Update**

Oh to be young, and not realize Rails 4 uses Strong Params. I understand the OP has already solved his original problem, but I'm going to correct this so it could actually be used as the right answer.

This would be a controller level issue, as Rails 4 requires you to whitelist attributes in the controller.

```
Ad.create(params[:ad].require(:ad).permit(:title, :price, :description))
```

Most of the time you'll be permitting the same params in the create and update action, so it's best to move it into its own method within the controller.

```
Ad.create(ad_params)
def ad_params
  params.require(:ad).permit(:title, :price, :description)
end
```

As OP pointed out in his comment, the permitted_params method he implemented was not being called from the permit.

Comment: my problem was passing wrong value to new method in create action, solution was to pass ad_params to it

Comment: This probably shouldn't be marked as the answer.

Comment: This is not the answer.

Comment: I agree, this doesn't help anything I experience the same issue and that answer didn't help anything I still get the ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError in PostsController error.

Comment: @Ömer Posted an update a few weeks to make it not wrong, see if that works for you.

Comment: i rewrite create active admin page controller and it helps me
http://pix.toile-libre.org/upload/original/1430911651.png

Comment: WIth the update I believe this answer is now correct.

Answer (score 32):

I also faced same problem and worked for 6 hours, and finally got the solution.

Try this Code, it will help you!
In Rails 4, this feature is added to deal with creation in different ways.

```
def new
  @ad = Ad.new
end

def create
  @ad = Ad.create(ad_params)
  @ad.save
end

private

def ad_params
  params.require(:ad).permit(:title, :price, :description)
end
```

Comment: title, price, description are the column name of table Ad

Answer (score 6):

Ad new before add params.permit!

```
   def create
     params.permit!
     @ad = Ad.new(params[:ad])    
     @ad.save
   end
```

Comment: Please take extreme caution when using this. From the Rails documentation:  "Extreme care should be taken when using permit! as it will allow all current and future model attributes to be mass-assigned."

Answer (score 1):

Your's should look like this:

```
def new
    @ad = Ad.new(params[:ad].permit(:title, :price, :description))
end
```

Mine looks like this:

```
def create
    @about = About.new(params[:about].permit(:introduction, :description))

    respond_to do |format|
        if @about.save
            format.html { redirect_to @about, notice: 'About was successfully created.' }
            format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @about }
        else
            format.html { render action: 'new' }
            format.json { render json: @about.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
    end
end
```