# Controller not accepting params value but the same value hard coded is accepted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, parameters

```
Rails.logger.info(params[:question])
=> {"title"=>"katt"}

@question_list.questions.create(params[:question])
=> ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError (ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError)
```

---

```
 @question_list.questions.create("title"=>"katt")
# SUCCES!
```

---

I cannot understand why Rails not accepts the params when the exact same value written by hand works fine?

**Update**
controller:

```
def new_question
  @question_list.questions.create(params[:question])
  render nothing: true
end

private
  def set_question_list
    @question_list = QuestionList.find(params[:id])
  end

  def question_list_params
    params.require(:question_list).permit(questions_attributes: [:id, :question_list_id, :title, :position, :_destroy])
  end
```

view:

```
<%= form_for @question_list, url: new_question_question_list_path, remote: true do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :title %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError when creating new user](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17335329/activemodelforbiddenattributeserror-when-creating-new-user)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17868685/1749024

Comment: @JKen13579 I've read dozens of questions on SO already. The value inserted is the same, so I cannot see how strong parameters is the problem?

Comment: Do you have a `question_params` method in your questions controller  that contains the line `params.require(:question).permit(:title)`?

Comment: `questions` are children of `question_list`. The code belongs to `QuestionListsController`. In the private method `question_list_params`: params.require(:question_list).permit(questions_attributes: [:id, :question_list_id, :title, :position, :_destroy])

Comment: Ah ok so you're not requiring/permitting `question`, you're instead permitting `questions_attributes`, which it seems like you aren't using. Can you post your full controller/form code for your `QuestionListsController`?

Comment: Can you also add your `new_question` form?

Comment: @JKen13579 OK updated.

Comment: Is `QuestionList` a separate model? How are `QuestionList` and `Question` associated? I don't see any `fields_for` in your form, which is used for nesting.

Comment: @KirtiThorat `QuestionList` one-to-many `Question`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23898486/controller-not-accepting-params-value-but-the-same-value-hard-coded-is-accepted?noredirect=1#comment36796949_23898486

Comment: Based on your controller and form, I'd suggest you try @zachar's solution. There is nothing in your code specifying that you're using "nested attributes", since you're sending a question to a question (within question_list) path, rather than sending a question list with a bunch of questions. If his solution doesn't work, I'll dig further for you.

Comment: Thank you for your time @JKen13579, really, but I don't understand you guys. Nested attributes is a really accepted pattern. In what way is my strong parameters method (`question_list_params`) wrong?

Comment: It's not that it's wrong, it's that you're not using it in your `new_question` method. Were a `question_list` object being passed with a list of questions (such as in a nested form) then you would be using your `question_list_params`, but you're passing a `question` object, as evidenced by the fact that you're using `params[:question]`. So, you need to let your controller know that you'd like to permit a question object. You do that by using a `question_params` method such as @zachar's. Hopefully that explanation helps... It's difficult to explain things in comments. :(

Comment: @Numbers can you confirm you have defined in your question_list model accepts_nested_attributes_for :questions

Comment: @numbers Just for the reference, I will attach one of my code that creates questions and all it's associated child(answer options) in single query. I hope that might give you some idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `Rails 4`, you would need to whitelist the attributes that you would like to be saved in database thats what *Strong Parameters* is all about. So, `@question_list.questions.create(params[:question])` is not going to work in controller and would result in `ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError`.

`QuestionList` has_many `Questions`, and you are trying to implement nested attributes, you should first start with fixing the form as there are NO nested attributes in there. Looking at the `question_list_params`, I can say that `Question` model has a field named `title`, so, your form should look something like:

```
<%= form_for @question_list, url: new_question_question_list_path, remote: true do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :questions do |ff| %>
    <%= ff.text_field :title %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Next thing that you can do is update the `new_question` method as below:

```
def new_question
  @question_list.update(question_list_params)
  render nothing: true
end
```

`@question_list.update(question_list_params)` would take care of updating the `question_list` record PLUS the nested attributes of `question`.

Refer to **[Active Record Nested Attributes For One-To-Many Association](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html#module-ActiveRecord%3a%3aNestedAttributes%3a%3aClassMethods-label-One-to-many)** for an example.

Answer (score 1):

It's a Rails 4 new feature, called strong parameters. Check it: http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html

You need to enable attributes in controller. Try something like that:

> class QuestionListsController < ApplicationController
>
> def create
>
> ```
> ...
>
> @question_list.questions.create(question_params)
> ```
>
> end
>
> ...
>
> private
>
> def question_params
>
> ```
> params.require(:question).permit(:title)
> ```
>
> end
>
> end

Comment: Thanks but my code has nested attributes and as you can see in the docs you provided (see the example with `Class Person`) there's  another kind of syntax for nested attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference:

```
#Create question and it's options including correct answers.
def create

    if params[:question].present?      
      @question = Question.create(question_params)     
    else
      message("Failed", "400", "Parameter missing!", "Invalid parameters")
    end

end

private  

def question_params
      params.require(:question).permit(:word_id, :question_string, :level, :answers_attributes => [ :answer_string, :is_correct_choice])
end
```

I hope it will help you debug your code. And as @kirti has already suggested you can use the same format to do rest of the operation as well.