# ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError using an older version of ruby?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am creating a blog using ruby on rails. I am following a tutorial that is using an older version on rails. I am trying to post comments about the blog post on the same page. whenever i hit the submit button i get this error message. 
 ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError

Extracted source (around line #44):

```
def create
@post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
@comment= @post.comments.new(params[:comment])

respond_to do |format|
  if @comment.save
```

Here is my code inside my controller

```
def create
  @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
  @comment= @post.comments.build(params[:comment])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @comment.save
      format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Comment was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render json: @post, status: :created, location: @comment }
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: Can you show comment.rb file's line which says: `attr_asseccible`, also post the form code.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are using Rails 4. If so, the needed parameters must be marked as required in controller.

You can refer `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17868427/rails-4-activemodelforbiddenattributeserror`