# Error when using attr_accessible and attr_accessor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a problem with `attr_accessible` and `attr_accessor`.

When I use attr_accessor in model:

> attr_accessor :crop_x, :crop_y, :crop_w, :crop_h
>
> attr_accessible :title, :author, :description, :price, :attach

**Error**:

```
Server return:
WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes for Product: crop_x, crop_y, crop_w, crop_h
```

I edited as follow:

> attr_accessible :title, :author, :description, :price, :attach
>
> attr_accessible :crop_x, :crop_y, :crop_w, :crop_h

**Error**:

```
Server return:
undefined method `crop_x' for #<Product:0x007fe900f88c20>
```

So, I used both `attr_accessible` and `attr_accessor`:

> attr_accessor :crop_x, :crop_y, :crop_w, :crop_h
>
> attr_accessible :title, :author, :description, :price, :attach
>
> attr_accessible :crop_x, :crop_y, :crop_w, :crop_h

But server run forever.

Comment: If you use Rails 4, please see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17371334/how-is-attr-accessible-used-in-rails-4/17371364#17371364

Comment: I added 4 fields: :crop_x, :crop_y, :crop_w, :crop_h into my database, and I solved this problem. It works normally.

Answer (score 0):

attr_accessor provides the setter and getter methods for attribute.
attr_accessible says that the attribute can be mass-assigned.