# Rails validates_presence_of and validates presence in has_one associated models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, associations, ruby-on-rails-4, models

I am having trouble saving objects to their corresponding tables.

Model Customer. I want to make sure it has an associated valid Account:

```
has_one :account, dependent: :destroy
validates_presence_of :account
validates_associated :account
```

Model Account belongs to Customer, so I want to enforce customer_id is present:

```
belongs_to :customer
validates :customer_id, presence: true
```

Now, my question is: Which order should I save these objects? Are these validations somewhat incompatible?

Because, if I try to save Customer first, it won't be possible, I will get

```
myCustomer.save.errors.messages
{:account=>["can't be blank"]}
```

Obviously, since I stated

```
validates_presence_of :account
```

in the model.

But if I try to save Account first, wait! I can't save it either! I have

> validates :customer_id, presence: true

in my Account model and I haven't saved any customer yet !

So I have also tried to just initialize the Account:

```
acc = Account.new(acc_attr: foo, acc_attr2: bar)
```

and then try to set it to Customer like this

```
Customer.account = acc
```

But then again, customer won't save since acc is not valid, (since it doesn't have a customer_id and I have validates_associated :account in the Customer model)

So, will I have to give up on one validation in either model? Is there a workaround for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can add this into your model:

```
attr_accessible: :customer_id
```

And add to GemFile:

```
gem 'devise', '3.0.0.rc' 
gem 'protected_attributes'
```

- run in terminal: $ bundle install
- reset server

You should check in your controller:

```
params.require(:account).permit(:customer_id)
```

Comment: What do I need devise for? Also, I have no controllers yet. I just want to save those objects.

Comment: Use `attr_accessible: :customer_id` to access database. And devise is used for attr_accessible. Controller is a option, if you have no any controller for your model, you don't need check in controller.

Comment: [Rails 4 uses strong parameters](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html). `attr_accessible` has been deprecated, as is noted [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/MassAssignmentSecurity/ClassMethods/attr_accessible). [This SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17371364) has a good description of how strong parameters work in place of `attr_accessible`.