# Strong Params, Nested Attributes and Mongoid don't seem to work because of *_attributes suffix in form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters

I'm trying to embed property groups on my main Person model to help keep my code organised but Rails 4's Strong Params is getting in the way.

## The Scenario

I have a `Person` model and a `PersonName` model like so:

```
class Person
  include Mongoid::Document
  embeds_one :name, class_name: 'PersonName'
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :name
end

class PersonName
  include Mongoid::Document
  embedded_in :person, inverse_of: :name
  # fields here
end
```

I then use the `fields_for` helper in my form to nest the `PersonName` attributes in the `Person` `_form`:

```
<%= f.fields_for :name, PersonName.new do |builder| %>
  <!-- etc -->
```

and finally I permit the name attributes in the controller so that Strong Params allows the nested attributes through:

```
def person_params
  params.require(:person).permit(:name)
end
```

## The Problem

It doesn't work and I get the error `Unpermitted parameters: name_attributes`. What's happening is when I call `f.fields_for :name ...` a "_attributes" get's appended to the fields in the HTML form. e.g. If I have a field `first_name` then the form looks like this:

```
<input name="person[name_attributes][first_name] ...>
```

instead of:

```
<input name="person[name][first_name] ...>
```

As far as I can tell this is intended behavior, so it seems like the `.permit` method is where things are failing to work.

### Attempted Work Arounds

I've tried changing the  Strong Params line to:

```
params.require(:person).permit(:name_attributes)
```

but this doesn't work. Using `permit!` *does* work, but I don't like it since as far as I can tell it's a complete anti-pattern.

I've also tried changing `:name` everywhere to `:name_attributes`, except in the `f.fields_for` helper, since the HTML form now had a property that actually existed on my model. Unfortunately this resulted in `f.fields_for :name` yielding an error saying `:name` is not a valid proterty.

Comment: Please see answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17371334/how-is-attr-accessible-used-in-rails-4/17371364#17371364

Answer (score 3):

Pierre-Louis Gottfrois, was right, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17371334/how-is-attr-accessible-used-in-rails-4/17371364#17371364) fixes my problem. Specifically I needed to add:

```
params.require(:person).permit(name_attributes: [:first_name, ...])
```

with the key thing being `name_attributes` followed by a list of the symbols that I wanted to permit.

Comment: You may also need to include :id (ie, name_attributes [:id, :first_name]) when editing / updating a pre-existing record, or else it will create duplicate new names instead of updating the old ones.