# Upgrade timing for Rails on new OS X?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, macos, osx-mountain-lion, osx-mavericks

Looks like Apple just released OS X 10.9 Mavericks, and I'm thinking about upgrading from 10.8 Mountain Lion.  I'm running Rails 3.2.15 with Ruby 1.9.3.

I have several things to potentially upgrade, and they're not necessarily related:

```
OS X 10.8  --> 10.9
Rails 3.2  -->  4.0
Ruby 1.9.3 -->  2.0
```

What is the timing cycle usually like for new gems, etc to cooperate nicely with OS X?  Is it better to wait a week, or a month, or several months?  Or would it be pretty seamless to upgrade OS X and then upgrade Ruby + Rails?

Answer (score 1):

There are not a whole lot of differences between Ruby 1.9.3 and Ruby 2.0, though I've had one gem trip me up in the upgrade. If you find that you need to use 1.9.3 still you can install brew (http://brew.sh/) and RVM (http://rvm.io/) to help you manage multiple Ruby versions. Please note you'll have to install XCode and/or it's commandline tools to compile software.

The biggest change I have found with Rails 4.0 is how it handles whitelisting of attributes to be used in models. Instead of using attr_accessible in your model, use [strong parameters](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html) in the controller. You can see how to use them in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17371334/how-is-attr-accessible-used-in-rails-4).

As far as how they handle on the new OS, it may still be a little too early to say if there is any wonkiness involved. I usually go a couple of months before upgrading just of that reason.