# Strong parameters - Devise 3.0.0 and Rails 4. "Unpermitted parameters: name"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am currently using Rails 4 and Devise 3.0.0. I have tried to add a custom field of "Name" to the sign up form and edit registration form. Whenever I submit the form, the following errors arise:

```
Unpermitted parameters: name

WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes for User: email, password, password_confirmation.
```

I understand that this has something to do with the way Rails 4 handles parameters, but I do not understand what I am supposed to do about it right now. I have searched around and have seen that I am supposed to add some lines to a User model involving "params."

My user model currently looks like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, #:recoverable,
          :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  attr_accessible :name, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :email
end
```

According to [How is attr_accessible used in Rails 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17371334/how-is-attr-accessible-used-in-rails-4), I am supposed to add the following code to "The controller."

```
class PeopleController < ApplicationController
  def create
    Person.create(person_params)
  end

  private

  def person_params
    params.require(:person).permit(:name, :age)
  end
end
```

What controller? And is this literal code? Since I am dealing with User, do I have to use User.create(user_params)? instead of Person.create(person_params)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add this in controller where you have written User.create(user_params). I am assuming that UsersController.

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def create
    User.create(user_params)
  end

  private

  def user_params
#assumption: user params are coming in params[:user]
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :age, :and_other_params_you_want_to_allow)
  end
end
```

Comment: For some reason Rails failed to create a Users controller. Let me create one and get back to you.

Comment: Can you tell me the URL where your User form is posted to?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "URL where User form is posted to." However, I created a users_controller.rb and wrote in the code you mentioned and this is what I am getting:

Unpermitted parameters: name
WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes for User: email

@techvineet

Answer (score 4):

Rails 4 has moved parameter sanitisation to the Controller from the Model. Devise handles it for 3 actions, sign_in, sign_up and account_update. For sign_up, the permitted parameters are `authentication key` (which is `:email` by default), `password` and `password_confirmation`.

If you want to add `:name` to the `User` model and use it for sign_up, either change `config.authentication_keys = [ :email ]` to `config.authentication_keys = [ :name ]` in `/config/initializers/devise.rb` or, if you want to use both `:email` and `:name`, add this to the `ApplicationController`

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :username
  end    
end
```

Also check-
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#strong-parameters

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should add one line which is like:-

```
attr_accessible :name
```

in your model to allow name to assigned and if it does not work try this [How is attr_accessible used in Rails 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17371334/how-is-attr-accessible-used-in-rails-4)

Comment: I have just added my User model to the question. I actually do have that line in there. I will read your link now.

Comment: I have updated the question with more information from the link you provided. I am unsure how to implement what it says.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problem. So, to fix it I created custom  registration controller inherit form DeviseRegistration controller. Check Devise documentation and define controller like this.

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  before_filter :update_sanitized_params, if: :devise_controller?


  def update_sanitized_params
   devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) {|u| u.permit(:name, :email, :)}
 end
end
```

Make sure you have define this routes for this controller in config/routes.rb

```
  devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => "registrations" } , :path => '', :path_names => {
    :sign_in => 'login', 
    :sign_out => 'logout'
  }
```

[Check this documentation of devise for strong parameter.](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#strong-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

i had similar issues, this was my fix:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { |u| u.permit!}
  end
end
```