# undefined method `first_name' for nil:NilClass - No way this is Nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

User has many comments, comment belongs to many users. How do I fix this error?

> undefined method `first_name' for nil:NilClass

when I try to do

```
   <h3>Comments</h3>
     <% @guide.comments.each do |comment| %>
       <div>
         <p><%= comment.user.first_name %></p>
       </div>
     <% end %>
```

user.rb

```
has_many :comments
```

comment.rb

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

comments migration (I added a user_id column):

```
class CreateComments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :comments do |t|
      t.text :body
      t.integer :user_id

      t.timestamps
      add_foreign_key :comments, :guides
    end
  end
end
```

comments controller:

```
def create
    @comment = Comment.new(comment_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @comment.save
        format.html { redirect_to @comment, notice: 'Comment was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @comment }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @comment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: The code given here is not wrong. Maybe something wrong with the way you are creating the comments objects. Can you post that code?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @sawa - How do I fix the error? To display the user of the comment?.

Comment: @arun15thmay - I used the rails g scaffold. Maybe it bugged out? I'll post it still.

Comment: Can you give code for the create action in comments controller?

Comment: Just did @arun15thmay

Comment: Can you check my answer?

Comment: How is `@guide` initialized? Can you post that code?

Answer (score 1):

long time ago but this could be usefull for someone with the same error.
you should `delegate` the `first_name` to the `user` and allow nil

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  delegate :first_name, to: :user, allow_nil: true, prefix: true
end
```

then call it in you view with

```
<h3>Comments</h3>
  <% @guide.comments.each do |comment| %>
    <div>
      <p><%= comment.user_first_name %></p>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

if there is no user, then it will be display nothing and not raise an exception

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you did not set the user id while creating the comment object. can you try the following code?

```
def create
    @comment = current_user.comments.new(comment_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @comment.save
        format.html { redirect_to @comment, notice: 'Comment was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @comment }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @comment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: @DylanRichards the problem is that you have comments that do not belong to a user. Clear your database first and then try again with the above code.

Comment: @DylanRichards Can you check your database if the user_id is not nil for the comments??

Comment: @arun15thmay instead of merging params you could simply do: `current_user.comments.build(comment_params)`. Much cleaner IMHO.

Comment: There are no comments in the database. Not sure how user_id would be nil then. Give me a second to run the above code again.

Comment: @DylanRichards If there are no comments, it shouldn't even go into the iteration and you wouldn't get that error. You must be doing *something* wrong, but from what you're showing us I cannot determine what exactly.

Comment: @DylanRichards As far as I can see, that controller part of you code is definitely wrong. Try creating new comments and check if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you user model has a `first_name` attribute. Then confirm that your comment record (s) actually have a user associated with them. You may not have the user_id column whitelisted in the Comment class, so the user is not set

```
class Comment
  attr_accessible :user_id, ...
end
```

Or in rails 4 you have strong parameters instead of attr_accessible

[How is attr_accessible used in Rails 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17371334/how-is-attr-accessible-used-in-rails-4)

Comment: I'm permitting that in my params hash.

Comment: I would use the console to investigate what attributes you have set on the comments. `rails c` `Comment.first` ensure you do have user_id set. OR check them all `Comment.all.map(&:user_id)`

Comment: Or even more concisely `Comment.pluck(:user_id)`. Any nil values are telling that the foreign key is not getting set.

Comment: `Comment.pluck(:user_id)` is returning an empty array.

Comment: If you don't have any comment records, then this should not occur. Are you getting the error when using the default development environment? Just ensuring you are not troubleshooting separate development and production databases. If you are still stuck, delete the databases and start again. Ensure you have a clean slate.

Answer (score 0):

Model didn't find comment.user. It may be the comment's user_id havn't been set or the user_id didn't apper in "user" table "id" column. You can print the comment id and comment.user_id and check in DB.

Do you set：

```
has_many :comments， ：dependent => :destroy
```

Or it could hapeen you delete the user but the user's comments remain, then for these comments, comment.user is null.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your user_id is set when you create a comment ?
Maybe this simple line is missing in your controller

```
    @comment.user = current_user
```

In order to be sure to have a user in your comment, you should add in your Comment model

```
validates_presence_of :user_id
```

and in your User model

```
has_many :comments， ：dependent => :destroy
```

Answer (score -1):

Defining methods in Ruby is very simple. To solve your problem, define

```
class << nil
  def first_name; "John" end
  def last_name; "Doe" end
end
```

And the error will disappear. All the `nil` objects are now named "John Doe".