# When I submit content in Rails 4, an alert incorrectly says there are two errors?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When submitting a form (title and content that should pass), I get the following:

[image]

Next, in **events.rb**, I commented out the validation requirements:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
    #validates :title, presence: true,
    #                length: { minimum: 5 }
end
```

After that, the form would let me submit an event post, but everything was blank, as shown:

[image]

As a note, my submissions were working until around the time I submitted Devise, and made a few other changes with adding a user model. Please take a look and let me know what I can do about this.

Answer (score 1):

In your `events_controller.rb`, you need to permit the desired user-editable parameters, and create your event with that.

```
Event.create!(event_params)

def event_params
  params.require(:event).permit(:title, :description)
end
```

Comment: Hi Brian, thanks for the help. I tried this but it did not work. I made the assumption to put `@event = Event.create!(event_params)`, but the outcome was same as before. I also tried w/o the `@event` and got a red-screen error saying the same thing about 2 errors. I had "event params" in the private area of the controller from before, so did not make changes to that. Anything else I might be missing?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want it to be blank, then you will still need

```
validates :title, presence: true
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this but it still gives me the title error (ie it says there is no title.) Any other possibilities I may have missed?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your EventsController in git repo, I see that in your create action you are creating the event instance as follows:

```
    @event = Event.new(params[:event].permit(:title, :text))
```

Change that to

```
    @event = Event.new(event_params)
```

Or

```
    @event = Event.new(params.require(:event).permit(:title, :text))
```

you can check it by turning on the validations, It should work now.

Comment: Hi Kirti, I tried this but it did not work. Thanks for checking out my Git repo. Unfortunately I got the exact same errors as before, trying both of your suggestions. Any other possibilities you might know of?

Comment: Do you mean that you are inputting a title with length more than 5 i.e., a perfectly valid title which should pass the validations then submitting the form and you get the same error saying "Title can't be blank"?

Comment: Yes, I can put a whole book and it keeps saying I am doing the wrong thing. It says 2 errors, cannot be blank and 'is less than 5 characters.' I think it has something to do with my inclusion of the gem 'protected-attributes.' [This link](https://teamtreehouse.com/forum/build-a-simple-ruby-on-rails-application-generating-the-user-model-problems-every-time-i-enter-a-email-and-password-it-says-its-blank) seems to address what I mean, I'm trying to figure it out right now.

Comment: I do think it is the attr_accessible, but I get `attr_accessible is extracted out of Rails into a gem. Please use new recommended protection model for params(strong_parameters) or add protected_attributes to yourGemfile to use old one. (RuntimeError)`. I will try to fix that without using the gem. Do you know how I might do that easily, given the provided info?

Comment: Attr_accessible was removed from Rails4 due to the introduction of strong parameters. I am not sure why you are using that gem because I don't think it's required if you are using Rails4. You can refer to this question for details : (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17371334/how-is-attr-accessible-used-in-rails-4)

Comment: @CodeWalrus is your problem resolved? Or still there?

Comment: Hi Kirti, I'll update my original post with replies from now on, since S.O is saying that the comments are getting a bit long. For now, I excluded the line `attr_accessible :email, :password,  [...]`. Now it isn't broken, but might be unprotected from mischevious users. I don't have a user controller yet, so can't do certain parameter changes (as in your link). I installed the gem because Rails said to, if I wanted to use attr accesible. A tutorial I'm doing wants attr, but the tut uses Rails 3.2, so I'm trying to adapt it.

Comment: If you want to use `attr_accessible` as required by the tutorial, then you can create a new gemset(using rvm) for your application by installing Rails 3.2 gem in it.