# rails 4 how to add custom form fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

How can we add custom form fields in rails 4.

For ex: 
**User** (model)
username
email
hashed_password

Now in the form field for `password` I would like to have fields like `password` and `password confirm`.
But due to the introduction of strong parameters in rails 4, I cannot simply send those fields . 
It throws error.

It used to be a piece of cake in prior versions of rails i.e in the model we would add our custom form fields to `attr_accessor` and we could play with them.

NOTE: I tried this thing few weeks ago and it did'nt work, and I don't remember the exact error but was something like 'no method password on user'. 
I know it is very stupid of me to not provide you with the exact error messages.
My apologies, can't help I deleted the application.

I was following this tutorial (it's for rails 3) http://www.sitepoint.com/rails-userpassword-authentication-from-scratch-part-i/

Comment: Why? `params.require(:user).permit(:password, :password_confirm)` should work well

Answer (score 2):

Check out **[How is attr_accessible used in Rails 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17371334/how-is-attr-accessible-used-in-rails-4)**  for using strong parameters in rails 4

Protecting attributes is now done in the Controller.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using `attr_accessor` in model in Rails 4.

In forms I have

```
<%= text_field_tag 'param_name' %>
```

And in controller

```
@model.param_name = params[:param_name]
```

It works ok and can solve your problem, I think. BUT! **I'm not sure it is secure to use it this way.** If someone can explain, why it is not appropriate for security reasons and suggest a better way, I'll appreciate it (as the author, I think).

Comment: attr_accessor is no longer available in rails 4, it has been extracted to a gem.

Comment: Ok. But I'm using it (in Rails 4.0.2), and I don't have `protected_attributes` gem in my Gemfile. You mean, that it throws you an error, when you use `attr_accessor` in your model file?

Comment: I didn't even bother using attr_accessor coz i knew it's not gonna help. Nor did I tried 'protected_attributes' coz i didn't want to depend on something which is deprecated. I got this error in the controller from the `params.require(:user).permit(:password, :password_confirm)`