# How to create an object automatically after initialising object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `Task` and a `Tick`. After the user creates a `Task`, I want to automatically create a `Tick`.

```
  def create
      @task = current_user.tasks.build(task_params)

      @task.category_id = params[:category_id]

      respond_to do |format|
          if @task.save
              format.html { redirect_to tasks_path, notice: 'Task was successfully created.' }

            # @task.ticks.build(user_id: @user, complete: false) # doesn't create tick, but shows no error
            # Tick.create(user_id: @user.id, tick_id: @tick.id, complete: false) #error: undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass
          else
              format.html { render :new }
          end
     end
  end
```

Tick model:

```
class Tick < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :task
   belongs_to :user
end
```

Task model

```
class Task < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :category
    has_many :ticks
end
```

I've tried all the answers from [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23001259/creating-an-activerecord-object-from-another-controller-am-i-doing-it-correctl):

This, on the line above `respond_to do |format|`

```
@task.ticks.build(user_id: @user, complete: false)
```

*(which throws NoMethodError in Tasks#create ... undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass)*

---

I've these after `if @task.save`

```
@task.ticks.build(user_id: @user, complete: false)
```

*(doesn't create tick, but shows no error)*

```
Tick.create(user_id: @user.id, tick_id: @tick.id, complete: false)
```

*(Throws error: undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass)*

---

Also, is there a technical name for what I'm trying to do?

Comment: try this `@task.ticks.create(user_id: current_user.id, complete: false)`

Comment: Solved @sa77  — thanks mate

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with a **model callback**

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :category
  has_many :ticks

  after_create :set_tick

  private

  def set_tick
    self.ticks.create!(user: self.user, complete: false)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your create action as per below, you does not need to build class object, just initialise your class object with current user reference.

```
    def create
      @task = current_user.tasks.new(task_params)

      @task.category_id = params[:category_id]

      respond_to do |format|
          if @task.save
              format.html { redirect_to tasks_path, notice: 'Task was successfully created.' }

            # @task.ticks.build(user_id: @user, complete: false) # doesn't create tick, but shows no error
            # Tick.create(user_id: @user.id, tick_id: @tick.id, complete: false) #error: undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass
          else
              format.html { render :new }
          end
     end
  end
```

here, you does not need to assign user_id to your object.