# Rails create! with nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-many, griddler

I'm writing to an email table every-time my app receives emails.

I'm passing in an email object to create the record, but failing to figure out how to translate the email.to property, which is an array of hashes.

I have the corresponding EmailAddress has many model set up with the proper attributes to transfer over!

The Email model  has_many :email_addresses, class_name: "EmailAddress", as: "email_addressable".

```
class EmailProcessor
  def self.process(email)
    Email.create!({ 
                    body:       email.body,
                    subject:    email.subject,
                    email_addresses: email.to
                  })
  end
end
```

An example of what I beleive the email.to would look like:

```
email.to = [{
  :token => "A",
  :email => "A2",
  :full  => "A3",
  :name  => "A4"
},{
  :token => "B",
  :email => "B2",
  :full  => "B3",
  :name  => "B4"
}]
```

Comment: As your email.to is array of hashes and you want to store that hashes as it is into your DB ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add `accepts_nested_attributes_for :email_addresses` within your Email model if you want to be able to create a new Email together with its associated new EmailAddresses using nested attributes. You could learn more from this StackOverflow answer: [How is attr_accessible used in Rails 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17371334/how-is-attr-accessible-used-in-rails-4)

I'm assuming you're using Rails 4.