# undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass - form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to add images as attachment to comments. Comments belong to a Post. I've looked at [**this**](https://gist.github.com/mhenrixon/978371) gist. I've also tried with nested_form gem, but still the same error.

form

```
<%= semantic_form_for([@post, @comment], validate: true, html: {multipart: true}, 'data-update-target' => 'comments', class: 'comments') do  |f| %>

<%= f.text_field :title %>

<%= f.semantic_fields_for :comment_images do |pic| %>
  <%= pic.inputs do %>
    <%= pic.hidden_field :id %>
    <%= pic.hidden_field :attachable_id %>
    <%= pic.hidden_field :attachable_type %>
    <%= pic.file_field :image %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
...
```

comment_image model

```
class CommentImage < ActiveRecord::Base  
  belongs_to :attachable, polymorphic: true
  attr_accessible :image, :attachable_id, :attachable_type
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader 

end
```

comment model

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessor :image, :file

has_many :comment_images, :as => :attachable, :dependent => :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :comment_images, :allow_destroy => true
```

server log

```
Started GET "/posts/1/comments/new" for ....136 at 2014-04-28 16:41:47 +0000                                                                                               
Processing by CommentsController#new as HTML                                                                                                                                       
  Parameters: {"post_id"=>"1"}                                                                                                                                                        
  Post Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "1"]]                                                                                      
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]                                                                                        
params********************{"action"=>"new", "controller"=>"comments", "post_id"=>"1"}                                                                                             
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 9ms                                                                                                                                            

NoMethodError - undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass:                                                                                                                               
  activerecord (4.0.4) lib/active_record/attribute_methods/read.rb:86:in `block in read_attribute'                                                                                    
  activerecord (4.0.4) lib/active_record/attribute_methods/read.rb:84:in `read_attribute'                                                                                             
  activerecord (4.0.4) lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:344:in `[]'                                                                                                             
  activerecord (4.0.4) lib/active_record/associations/association_scope.rb:73:in `block in add_constraints'                                                                           
  activerecord (4.0.4) lib/active_record/associations/association_scope.rb:44:in `add_constraints'                                                                                    
  activerecord (4.0.4) lib/active_record/associations/association_scope.rb:19:in `scope'                                                                                              
  activerecord (4.0.4) lib/active_record/associations/association.rb:103:in `association_scope'                                                                                       
  activerecord (4.0.4) lib/active_record/associations/association.rb:87:in `scope'                                                                                                    
  activerecord (4.0.4) lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:382:in `scope'                                                                                        
  activerecord (4.0.4) lib/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb:37:in `initialize'                                                                                          
  activerecord (4.0.4) lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:78:in `new'                                                                                                           
  activerecord (4.0.4) lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:37:in `reader'                                                                                        
  activerecord (4.0.4) lib/active_record/associations/builder/association.rb:70:in `comment_images'                                                                                    
  app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:18:in `new'                                                                                                                              
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'                                                                                                
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'                                                                                                          
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'                                                                                                  
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'                                                                                             
  activesupport (4.0.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:433:in `_run__1580909207748771124__process_action__callbacks'                                                                 
  activesupport (4.0.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'                                                                                                         
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'                                                                                                      
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'                                                                                                     
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'                                                                                   
  activesupport (4.0.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'                                                                                              
  activesupport (4.0.4) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'                                                                                           
  activesupport (4.0.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'             
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'                                                                                            
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'                                                                                            
  activerecord (4.0.4) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'                                                                                        
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'                                                                                                                 
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:44:in `process'                                                                                                             
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'                                                                                                                 
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'                                                                                                  
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:231:in `block in action'                                                                                                          
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `dispatch'                                                                                                        
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:48:in `call'                                                                                                            
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'                                                                                                      
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'                                                                                                               
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:674:in `call'                                                                                                           
  omniauth (1.2.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:186:in `call!'                                                                                                                            
  omniauth (1.2.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in `call'                                                                                                                             
  omniauth (1.2.1) lib/omniauth/builder.rb:59:in `call'                                                                                                                               
  meta_request (0.3.0) lib/meta_request/middlewares/app_request_handler.rb:13:in `call'                                                                                               
  rack-contrib (1.1.0) lib/rack/contrib/response_headers.rb:17:in `call'                                                                                                              
  meta_request (0.3.0) lib/meta_request/middlewares/headers.rb:16:in `call'                                                                                                           
  meta_request (0.3.0) lib/meta_request/middlewares/meta_request_handler.rb:13:in `call'                                                                                              
  newrelic_rpm (3.8.0.218) lib/new_relic/rack/error_collector.rb:55:in `call'                                                                                                         
  newrelic_rpm (3.8.0.218) lib/new_relic/rack/agent_hooks.rb:32:in `call'                                                                                                             
  newrelic_rpm (3.8.0.218) lib/new_relic/rack/browser_monitoring.rb:27:in `call'                                                                                                      
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'                                                                                                                                          
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'                                                                                                                                
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'                                                                                                                                          
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'                                                                                                     
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:241:in `call'                                                                                                            
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'                                                                                                                       
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'                                                                                                                          
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:486:in `call'                                                                                                          
  activerecord (4.0.4) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'                                                                                                                  
  activerecord (4.0.4) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:626:in `call'                                                                                
  activerecord (4.0.4) lib/active_record/migration.rb:373:in `call'                                                                                                                   
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'                                                                                                
  activesupport (4.0.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in `_run__2395107169417203351__call__callbacks'                                                                           
  activesupport (4.0.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'                                                                                                         
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:64:in `call'                                                                                                          
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'                                                                                                         
  better_errors (1.1.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:84:in `protected_app_call'                                                                                                    
  better_errors (1.1.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:79:in `better_errors_call'                                                                                                    
  better_errors (1.1.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:56:in `call'                                                                                                                  
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'                                                                                                  
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'                                                                                                   
  railties (4.0.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'                                                                                                                          
  railties (4.0.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'                                                                                                                     
  activesupport (4.0.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'                                                                                                  
  activesupport (4.0.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'                                                                                                           
  activesupport (4.0.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'                                                                                                           
  railties (4.0.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'                                                                                                                              
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'                                                                                                        
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'                                                                                                                                
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'                                                                                                                                       
  activesupport (4.0.4) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'                                                                                                 
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'                                                                                                                                          
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'                                                                                                            
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'                                                                                                                                     
  railties (4.0.4) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'                                                                                                                                  
  railties (4.0.4) lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'                                                                                                                              
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'                                                                                                                                          
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'                                                                                                                                
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'                                                                                                                            
  /home/action/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'                                                                                      
  /home/action/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'                                                                                           
  /home/action/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

Comment: Can you share the server log generated for this error.

Comment: Can you post the full error log. The one after `NoMethodError - undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: Let's debug this on chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48530/ror

Comment: It's updated with full code

Comment: It's updated with server log. What do you think?

Comment: in line 18 the object you expect to be initialized is not, so that causes the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with

```
attr_accessible :image, :attachable_id, :attachable_type
```

I had 'protected_attributes' gem, but I still had to create controller with strong_parameters instead to make it work. More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17371334/how-is-attr-accessible-used-in-rails-4?answertab=votes#tab-top).