# In Rails 4.0, where is the data that was originally defined by attr_accessible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am following One Month Rails screen cast tutorial. Since they use Rails 3 in the video, the attr_accessible attribute no longer works in rails 4. In the video they added a **name** parameter to attr_accessible

```
attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :name
```

In my attempt to follow the tutorial, I simply ignore this line completely since there was no attr_accessible for me to begin with. Magically, it works perfectly. How is this working, or is it only working on the surface but not really if I continue on with the project ?

In this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17371334/how-is-attr-accessible-used-in-rails-4) asked by someone else, the answer says attr_accessible is now redefined as **strong parameters** and everything is now in the controller. But I also did not mess with any controller (in fact I havn't generated a new controller since I started the project). Should I be worrying or is this all part of rails magic?

Comment: Strong Parameters are now handle that functional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Mass Assignment**

The [`strong parameters`](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters) methodology replaced `attr_accessible` in Rails 4 - it's basically a way to prevent [mass assignment](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/mass-assignment-rails-and-you--net-31695) with your `models`.

`Mass Assignment` is where a malicious user will set many different param settings at once (over and above the ones you want). `strong params` was introduced to only allow certain data to populate your model, thus preventing the `mass assignment` issue

With Rails 4, you can *read* any data you want from the model, but when you're populating a new object, you'll only be able to submit data which has been whitelisted by a `strong_params` method, like this:

```
#app/controllers/your_controller.rb
class YourController < ApplicationController
   def create
      @model = Model.new(model_params)
   end

   private
   def model_params
       params.require(:model).permit(:your, :attributes)
   end
end
```

So the reason why you're able to get the app working without using `attr_accessible` is because you can pull data from the db without having to whitelist any param. You'll hit issues when you try and *create* data, which is where `strong params` come in

Comment: After looking through my scaffold generated content, I was able to locate where the strong parameters are. thanks!

Comment: After messing with it even more, I finally understand what you meant by "hit issues when you create data". But the problem I am facing now is that I do not have a User controller, so I am not sure where to put my strong parameters. I do, however, have a user Model. Can i put strong parameters there?