# Ruby on Rails does not write to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

I created a small form with two fields and in the future intend to expand this form with one or two fields. It turns out that the inclusion of the data in sqlite this not being done, but gives no error.

The application is being developed to be a to-do list.

Can you tell me the possible reasons?

I have a model:

```
class ToDoList < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :is_favorite, :name, :description
   has_many :tasks,  dependent: :destroy
   belongs_to :member
end
```

and controller:

```
class ToDoListsController < ApplicationController
    ...
     def new
        @todo_list = ToDoList.new

        respond_to do |format|
          format.html # new.html.erb
          format.json { render json: @todo_list }
        end
      end
    ...

 def create
    @todo_list = ToDoList.new(params[:todo_list])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @todo_list.save
        format.html { redirect_to @todo_list, notice: 'Todo list was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @todo_list, status: :created, location: @todo_list }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @todo_list.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end   
   end
```

views: new.html.erb

```
<h2> add new task</h2>

<%= render partial: 'to_do_list' %>
```

_to_do_list.httml.erb:

```
<%= form_for(@todo_list = ToDoList.new) do |f| %>
<%#= form_for(@todo_list) do |f| %>
    <% if @todo_list.errors.any? %>
        <div id="error_explanation">
          <h2><%= pluralize(@todo_list.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this todo_list from being saved:</h2>

          <ul>
            <% @todo_list.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
                <li><%= msg %></li>
            <% end %>
          </ul>
        </div>
    <% end %>

    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :name %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :name %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :description %><br />
      <%= f.text_area :description %>
    </div>
    <div class="actions">
      <%= f.submit %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: @DaveNewton, Name, Description, and the like can not be recorded, were never recorded. Only the date and id are saved (default).

Comment: Then you should show the code that saves the item.

Comment: If the date and id are saved, you must be doing a save somewhere (not in the code you're showing, but somewhere).  You now need to pass the form to the object when you save... something like @todo_item.create(params[:to_do_item])

Comment: Ya, @SteveTurczyn, code here:

`def create
    @todo_list = ToDoList.new(params[:todo_list])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @todo_list.save
        format.html { redirect_to @todo_list, notice: 'Todo list was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @todo_list, status: :created, location: @todo_list }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @todo_list.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end`

Comment: That's helpful. Could we see the "new.hmtl.erb" file as well?  Should be under app/views/to_do_list directory.

Comment: Ya. Edited. (:. The project also is in git, if you prefer: https://github.com/larissaamancio/studies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, the link to the github was very helpful.

The problem is the params hash that's coming in is called `to_do_list` NOT `todo_list`.  So you're mapping nothing to the object when you do `ToDoList.new(params[:todo_list]`   ...  you should be doing `ToDoList.new(params[:to_do_list])`.

In fact, since your model class is ToDoList the correct underscore usage is always `to_do_list`

I suggest you scan everywhere you've used "todo_list" or "@todo_list" and change it to "to_do_list" and "@to_do_list".   It's not absolutely necessary, but for consistency, and it's what people expect to see.

I've confirmed that fixes your problem.

Cheers
Steve

Comment: thanks for the help, I had not noticed! need to have more attention. :D

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to mass assign attributes. If you are using Rails 4 attr_accessible is depricated you have to use strong parameters in the controller to mass-assign, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/17371364/3197124 . Or try assigning individual parameters such as todo_list.name individually in your create.

Comment: yes, but OP hasn't reported a mass assignment error (or any error, for that matter)

Comment: I use rails 3.2. I'll try to add an entry each time to see if records, but this is not a bad practice?

Comment: <%= form_for(@todo_list = ToDoList.new) do |f| %>... this confuses me. You try something like <%= form_for(@todo_list, url: todo_list_path) do|f| %>? or actually probably url: todo_lists_path