# How to implement strong parameters in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters

I'm having trouble implementing strong parameters, receiving the Undefined Method attr_accessible error locally.

Could anyone explain what exactly I have done wrong here.

users_controller.rb:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    def new
        @user = User.new
    end

    def create
        @user = User.new(user_params)
        if @user.save
            redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Signed up!"
            else
            render "new"
        end
    end

    def user_params
        params.require(:user).permit(:username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end
end
```

And in user.rb:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation
    has_secure_password
    validates_presence_of :password, :on => :create
end
```

And perhaps a foolproof fix for this...I've tried a number of attempts but I just can't seem to get this right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

strong_params are usually done in the controller, not in the model. it's also described like this in the [api](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html). so, there's also no need for you to set `attr_accesible`. this way different controllers can also set different fields on a model, e.g. a backend users controller could be allowed to set an admin flag, while the users controller on the frontend is not allowed to do that.

so, your `user_params` method belongs in your `UsersController`, and the `create` and `update` action use `user_params` to filter out the params you don't allow to be set. e.g.:

```
@user = User.new(user_params)
```

Comment: there's no need for attr_accesible, just use user_params in the new action. i'll update my answer

Comment: It's fixed, would like to accept this as the answer now. Will run a few more tests.

Answer (score 1):

Rails 4 uses strong params by default, and you don't need attr_accessible. Also in rails 4 you permit params in the controller instead of the model.

[How is attr_accessible used in Rails 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17371334/how-is-attr-accessible-used-in-rails-4)

Comment: So can I just delete the line with attar_accessible in it?