# fields_for not creating a record when making a new parent record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-attributes, fields-for

I am trying to automatically create a child record (Participant) when I create a parent (Project) record. I can create the parent (Project) fine and, on other forms, I can create the child (Participant).  I cannot seem to create the child (Participant) at the same time as the parent.

I am on Rails 4, and so I've set my strong params carefully.  I just don't understand what I'm doing wrong.
Parent Controller:

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController

  def new_project
    @title = params[:ti]
    @project = Project.new  
    @project.participants.build
  end


def create_project
  @project = Project.new(project_params)
  @template = Template.find(params[:t]) 
   @project.participants.build
   @title = params[:ti]
  respond_to do |format|
     if @project.save
        @project.participants.save
        format.html { redirect_to new_milestones_path(:p => @project.id), notice: 'Great! We saved your project details.' }
      else
        format.html {   redirect_to  new_project_path(t: @template.id, ti: @title)         
 }
        format.json { render json: @project.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def project_params
    params.require(:project).permit( :id, :title, :starts, participants_attributes: [:id, :email, :title, :status, :project_id])
  end
end
```

Models:

```
 class Participant < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :project, inverse_of: :participants
   ........
 end

 class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :participants, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :project
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :participants, allow_destroy: true, reject_if: proc { |a| a["email"].blank? }
   .........
 end
```

Form:

```
 <%= form_for @project, url: create_project_path(ti: @title), html: { :multipart => true, :class=> "form-horizontal", id: "basicForm" }do |f| %> 

   <%= f.fields_for :participants do |ff|%>

     <%= ff.hidden_field :email, :value => current_user.email %>
     <%= ff.hidden_field :title, :value => 'Organizer' %>
     <%= ff.hidden_field :status, :value => 'accepted' %>

   <% end %> 
   <%=  f.text_field  :title, :placeholder => 'Your Project Title'%>
   <%=  f.text_field  :starts, :placeholder => 'mm/dd/yyyy'%>

   <%= f.submit ' SAVE PROJECT' %>  
 <% end %>
```

**UPDATE:**
I added @project.participants.build as Samo suggested (and I've updated my code above), which makes the fields_for visible...but my project doesn't save...it redirects back to new_project_path.

Comment: When doing nested forms I usually also have to add ```<association>_attributes``` to the ```attr_accessible``` list. So in your case, ```attr_accessible :participants_attributes```. Not sure if that's still the case in Rails 4. Also you should not need ```@participant = Participant.new``` in your ```create``` action. That's not doing anything.

Comment: Thank you, but attr_accessible is not longer needed... it's been replaced by strong params.....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17371334/how-is-attr-accessible-used-in-rails-4

Comment: Do your participant fields even show up on the form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I see the issue. In your `new_project` action, try this:

```
  def new_project
    @title = params[:ti]
    @project = Project.new  
    @project.participants.build
  end
```

To elaborate: `fields_for` is not going to render anything if the association is blank/empty. You need to have at least one `participant` returned by `@project.participants` in order to see its fields. `@project.participants.build` will simply insert a new instance of the `Participant` class into the association.

Comment: Thank you, I will have to try this later...as I am out.

Comment: The :participants fields WEREN'T showing up..you were right.  I added @project.participants.build and they show up...but it doesn't create my parent and child, it  calls the "else" redirect and redirects back to "new_project"....

Comment: If it's not saving, one of the objects must be invalid. Try to inspect the properties of ```@project``` and ```@project.participants.first``` before you save. See what's missing. Or use ```save!``` to throw an exception, which should tell you which validation failed.

Comment: Yup.  I was missing a required field.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

1. As you're using Rails 4 in your application, you don't need to call `accepts_nested_attributes_for`, because you are already calling `params.require`in your Controller.
2. After `@participant = Participant.new` you didn't call `Participant.save`action. You do call a `@project.save` inside your `if` condition and you should do that for your `@participant` too. You can call `@project.save` before redirecting to `project_path`. I'm not sure if that is a correct approach, but you can try if it works. :-)