# Cannot instance object with attr_accessible in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have created a Category class:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :name
    has_many :posts
end
```

When I created a new object:

```
category = Category.new(:name => "News")
```

I am getting this error:

```
`NoMethodError: undefined method 'attr_accessible' for Category(call 
'Category.connection' to establish a connection):Class  ...
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: What rails version are you using? This method was removed from ActiveRecord, and replaced with strong params

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use `attr_accessor`, not `attr_accessible`.

[attr_accessor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4370960/what-is-attr-accessor-in-ruby) is a Ruby method that defines setter and getter methods, while [attr_accessible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17371334/how-is-attr-accessible-used-in-rails-4) lets you whitelist ActiveRecord attributes for mass assignment.

Comment: i'm learnning tutorial
[learn ruby from scratch ](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gSf86udAntA&index=21&list=PLDmvslp_VR0xlwr5lAx2PDsZLu7oIOhpX)

in Video , use <code>attr_accessible</code>

Comment: Hmm, perhaps you are supposed to use attr_accessible. You may just need to install the https://github.com/rails/protected_attributes gem.

Comment: @nắnghuếyêugáihuế, `attr_accessible` is no longer valid for rails 4, instead there's `strong_parameters` now, this video is probably using a rails 3 version, and you're probably using a rails 4+ version

Answer (score 1):

This will fix your issue.

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base

    def user_params
      params.require(:name)
    end
    has_many :posts
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Use attr_accessor there.. it will help you to solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

Below should fix also.
No need to put ::Base -- you can remove it.

```
class Category < ActiveRecord
  attr_accessor :name
  has_many :posts
end
```