# Rails - Saving Objects with NOT NULL constraint

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a model called `Issue` that has the following database structure :

```
class CreateIssues < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :issues do |t|
      t.string :path, null: false
      t.string :filename, null: false
      t.string :name, null: false
      t.string :year
      t.integer :number
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

In my model tests, I use the following line :

`issue = Issue.create path: "test_path", filename: "test_filename", name: "test_name"`

... which raises an exception when saving :

```
 SQLite3::ConstraintException: NOT NULL constraint failed:
 issues.path: INSERT INTO "issues" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?)
```

From what I understand, when calling `create` or `new/save`, rails starts by inserting an entry with only the timestamps. I would expect the insert to contain all of the values that I have passed to the `create` method.  Am I missing a step in the creation process?

**EDIT :**

Basic information and steps:

- Using SQLite3
- Using Rails 4.2.1
- Using RSpec
- Generated the Issue model using `be rails generate model Issue`
- Added the `NULL` constraints afterwords by hand
- Did `be rake db:migrate` successfully
- Tried my code in various model spec files

Tried other models, I get generated SQL that only includes the timestamps.

**EDIT 2:**
Here is my Issue model :

```
class Issue < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :pending_issue
  has_one :watched_issue
  has_many :unmatched_issues

  validates :path, presence: true
  validates :filename, presence: true
  validates :name, presence: true

  attr_accessor :path
  attr_accessor :filename
  attr_accessor :name
  attr_accessor :year
  attr_accessor :number
end
```

Comment: Something is fishy here -- Starting from a new app this code works fine for me. Is there more code that you could share? Or other steps you took along the way to get to this current state?

Comment: @GavinMiller Edited with as much detail as I can give you

Comment: I got a similar error when I made a typo in a migration and had to rollback and re-migrate. The test database didn't catch the changes for some reason. See answer below.

Comment: @AFaderDarkly Made new edit with the model info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your result is anomalous. This is what I get:

```
# migration
class CreateIssues < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :issues do |t|
      t.string :path, null: false

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Then in the console:

```
Issue.create path: "path"
# (0.1ms)  begin transaction
# SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "issues" ("path", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["path", "path"], ["created_at", "2015-06-21 16:55:08.304653"], ["updated_at", "2015-06-21 16:55:08.304653"]]
# (0.8ms)  commit transaction
# => #<Issue id: 1, path: "path", created_at: "2015-06-21 16:55:08", updated_at: "2015-06-21 16:55:08">
```

My test:

```
require "test_helper"

describe Issue do

  it "can be created" do
    Issue.create path: "test_path"
  end
end
```

passes. No exception.

What I think may have happened is that your database schema has become out of date on your test database.

Firstly, does a similar 'create' work in the development (default) rails console? If so, it's a big indication that something is very different in your test and development environments.

What happens if you force the console to use the test environment?

```
RAILS_ENV=test rails c
```

Does it work here?

I think you may need to manually rollback your test database to the migration which first created your issues table, then re-migrate

```
RAILS_ENV=test rake db:rollback
```

Keep applying until you reach the appropriate migration, then:

```
RAILS_ENV=test rake db:migrate
```

Does that help?

EDIT:

This appears to be the issue:

```
attr_accessor :path
attr_accessor :filename
attr_accessor :name
attr_accessor :year
attr_accessor :number
```

These will overwrite the Rails default accessors, at a guess. They are certainly not needed.

Comment: Can I do `rake db:reset` and start from scratch?

Comment: Did as you said, doesn't work. Running the console in test environnment gives the same result and rollback doesn't solve the issue either

Comment: Answer updated. Remove your attr_accessor declarations: Rails does not need them, and they may well be overwriting the ActiveRecord functionality. I will run some tests.

Comment: YES! I think it worked!! Here is a link to a SO question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17371334/how-is-attr-accessible-used-in-rails-4

Comment: Yes, if I add an attr_accessor, I get your error: ```ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::ConstraintException: NOT NULL constraint failed: issues.path: INSERT INTO "issues" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?)```

Answer (score 0):

Did you accidentally omit attr_accessible for :path?

Comment: I'm using Rails 4.2.1, and if I am not mistaken, attr_accessible is deprecated.