# has_one - how to assign_id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

There is a cool feature for `has_many` in Rails. I can write

```
class Article < AR::Base
  has_many :comments
  has_one  :another_association
```

and voila! method `comment_ids=` created, which I can use in strong parameters and mass assignment. Somethind like `@article.comment_ids = [1,2,3]`

I need something similar for `has_one`, like `@article.another_association_id = 1`. But I get `NoMethodError` exception. Is there any way to make this method works?

Answer (score 1):

Has one has a different syntax.

```
@article.build_another_association
@article.create_another_association
```

See the [guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-one-association-reference) for more info

Comment: I know it, I'm trying to hack it ;)

Comment: So use `@article.another_association = @another_association`, where `@another_associaion = Association.find(5)` for example.

Comment: Should I send this via parameters in controller? :D

Answer (score 0):

Use [`attr_accessible`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/attr_accessible/class)

> Specifies a white list of model attributes that can be set via mass-assignment

So you can add it like this assuming you created and ran the migration already:

```
class Article < AR::Base
  has_many :comments
  has_one  :another_association
  attr_accessible :another_association_id
```

But if it's Rails 4 you may need to [handle it in the controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17371334/how-is-attr-accessible-used-in-rails-4).

Answer (score 0):

You have the direction of the association reversed.

- With `has_one`, the other class should have an `article_id` to refer to a record in your `articles` table.
- If you want `articles.another_association_id`, then you should specify `belongs_to :another_association`.

> This method should only be used if the other class contains the foreign key. If the current class contains the foreign key, then you should use belongs_to instead.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_one

Comment: I think the OP mistakenly wrote his example backwards because the same thing should be true for his `has_many` example. But he claims that `@article.comment_ids = [1,2,3]` works. Even though that would also require `belongs_to :comment`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to simulate the way `has_many` works you could try this:

```
class Article < AR::Base
  has_one :page

  def page_id=(int_id)
    self.page = Page.find(int_id)
  end

end

@article.page_id = 3
```