# get id for list while adding item in form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models: `List` and `Item`. While adding items, I need to get `list_id`:

Here is my code:

In items_controler.rb

```
def new
  @item = Item.new
end
```

In app/models/item.rb

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :list
    attr_accessible :list_id
end
```

And this is my form:

```
<%= form_for(@item, remote: true, :html => { :role => "form" }) do |f| %>

<div id="error_explanation" class="bg-danger text-danger"></div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.label :name, :class => "control-label" %>
            <%= f.text_field :name, :class => "form-control first_input"  %>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.label :color, :class => "control-label" %>
            <%= f.text_field :color, :class => "form-control"  %>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.radio_button :priority, 'top', :checked => true %> 
            <%= label :priority_top, 'Place at the top of the list' %><br/>
            <%= f.radio_button :priority, 'bottom' %>
            <%= label :priority_bottom, 'Place at the bottom of the list' %>
            <%= f.hidden_field :list_id, :value => params[:list_id] %>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
                <%= f.submit  @item.new_record? ? "Create Item" : "Update Item", :class => "btn btn-primary" %>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<% end %>
```

Now em getting the error on page load

```
undefined method `attr_accessible' for #<Class:0xb3a2f928>
```

Is there any different way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need [`nested resources`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources):

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :lists do
   resources :items, only: [:new, :create] #-> url.com/lists/:list_id/items/new
end

#app/controllers/items_controller.rb
class ItemsController < ApplicationController
    def new
       @list = List.find params[:list_id]
       @item = @list.items.new
    end

    def create
       @list = List.find params[:list_id]
       @item = @list.items.new list_params
       @item.save
    end

    private

    def list_params
       params.require(:list).permit(:x, :y, :z)
    end
end
```

This will allow you to access the `list` object, and create a nested `items` object for it to use.

--

You'll have to change your `form_for` to use the nested route path:

```
<%= form_for [@list, @item] do |f| %>
```

Comment: and the other routes for items remains unchanged right?

Comment: Sure, unless you want them to be available outside of a `list` -- in which case you'd add `resources :items` on its own

Comment: Now my link to new item's form is <%= link_to "add new item", new_item_path, remote: true, class: "btn btn-success" %>  How it will change?

Answer (score 1):

If you define `belongs_to :list`, you have automatic access to the `list` and `list_id` attributes, so you don't have to define any attribute accessors.

And BTW, `attr_accessible` is deprecated since Rails 2.3.8.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17371334/how-is-attr-accessible-used-in-rails-4

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `attr_accessible :list_id` in your Item class: just delete this line.

The database should have a field `items.list_id`, and Rails will automatically make getter/setters for this field, and the belongs_to association will add a bunch more methods to do with the item->list relationship.

If you want to control the permitted parameters, do it in the controller.

[How is attr_accessible used in Rails 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17371334/how-is-attr-accessible-used-in-rails-4)

Comment: i need to use list_id to pass it to hidden field in view , how should i pass it to view through controller's new action?

Comment: How you're using it in the form is fine, i think, it's hard to say as i don't really know what you're trying to do.

Comment: i'm saving item information with ajax but each item is associated to a list by many to one relationship , so i need list_id to save in item table

Comment: Yep, and is that not working properly at the moment?