# Trying to create an Admin user in devise, but I am getting an error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, admin

I have already set devise up and created a user model, and now I am trying to set up an admin without any luck. First I followed the steps in devise's documentation:

```
$ rails generate devise Admin
```

Updated my admin model to:

```
class Admin < ActiveRecord::Base
 devise :database_authenticatable, :registrable, :trackable, :timeoutable, :lockable  
end
```

Then I updated my migration to:

```
class DeviseCreateAdmins < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table(:admins) do |t|
      t.string :email,              :null => false, :default => ""
      t.string :encrypted_password, :null => false, :default => ""
      t.integer  :sign_in_count, :default => 0
      t.datetime :current_sign_in_at
      t.datetime :last_sign_in_at
      t.string   :current_sign_in_ip
      t.string   :last_sign_in_ip
      t.integer  :failed_attempts, :default => 0 # Only if lock strategy is      :failed_attempts
      t.string   :unlock_token # Only if unlock strategy is :email or :both
      t.datetime :locked_at
      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :admins
  end
end
```

then I go to /admins/sign_up and I get this error:

```
NoMethodError in Devise::Registrations#new
undefined method `title' for #<Admin:0x00000005fb17b0>
<%= f.text_field :title, autofocus: true %>
```

Does the title actually have to be defined,or is something else causing this?
Is there a better way to create a single admin account in devise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not create the `title` column for your `Admin` model (admins table) - thus exception.

You should read about adding columns to table in Rails.

To resolve this specific issue create new migration:

```
rails g migration add_title_to_admins
```

In generated file:

```
add_column :admins, :title, :string
```

Run the migration:

```
rake db:migrate
```

Now your admins will have `title`. To add new attributes (columns in db) follow the instructions as for `title`.

Answer (score 0):

As Andrey pointed out, you must add the `title` column to your `Admin` table and then (if Rails 3) make the it [`attr_accessible`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17371334/how-is-attr-accessible-used-in-rails-4) in the `Admin` model, otherwise (if Rails 4) [white list the params](http://blog.trackets.com/2013/08/17/strong-parameters-by-example.html).

> Is there a better way to create a single admin account in devise?

Yes there is a better way to handle admin accounts. You should use the [rolify gem](https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify). It integrates seamlessly with devise and you don't need to have an entire separate table for the admin. Here is an example:

```
user = User.find(1)
user.add_role :admin # sets a global role
user.has_role? :admin
=> true
```

Comment: `attr_accessible`? khm-khm.. :)

Comment: @AndreyDeineko hmm I should be more specific, huh? Needs `attr_accessible` if the OP is using Rails 3 but needs to whitelist it in the controller if it's Rails 4.

Comment: rails 5 is about to be released, so I hope noone uses rails 3 by his will