# What happened to build() in Ruby on Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, attr-protected

I'm working with nested forms in Rails 4 / 5. Code that used `@my_model_instance.build` in Rails4 doesn't seem to work in Rails 5. I'm not sure if this is a bug or if its me.

**Details:**

*Rails 4.2.3 console:*

```
> @item = ItemType.new
=> #<ItemType id: nil, name: nil, .... >
> @item.item_abilities
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>
> @item.item_abilities.build
=> #<ItemAbility id: nil, item_type_id: nil, ... >
> @item.item_abilities
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<ItemAbility id: nil, item_type_id: nil, ... ]>
```

This works as documented/expected. Now lets try the same stuff on the same codebase in Rails 5 (rc2).

*Rails 5.0.0rc2 console:*

```
> @item = ItemType.new
=> #<ItemType id: nil, name: nil, .... >
> @item.item_abilities
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>
> @item.item_abilities.build
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 0..1)
from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.rc2/lib/active_record/core.rb:312:in `initialize'
from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.rc2/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:65:in `new'
from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.rc2/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:65:in `new'
from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/protected_attributes-1.1.3/lib/active_record/mass_assignment_security/reflection.rb:8:in `build_association'
from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/protected_attributes-1.1.3/lib/active_record/mass_assignment_security/associations.rb:7:in `build_record'
from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/protected_attributes-1.1.3/lib/active_record/mass_assignment_security/associations.rb:25:in `build'
from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/protected_attributes-1.1.3/lib/active_record/mass_assignment_security/associations.rb:64:in `build'
from (irb):2
from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.rc2/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:65:in `start'
from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.rc2/lib/rails/commands/console_helper.rb:9:in `start'
from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.rc2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `console'
from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.rc2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.rc2/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
from bin/rails:4:in `require'
from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

So is this something I'm doing, or is Rails5 crazy?

**Relevant sections of models:**

*item_type.rb*

```
class ItemType < ActiveRecord::Base
    ## Relationships
    belongs_to :item_collection
    has_many :item_abilities
    has_many :item_instances

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :item_abilities

    ...
end
```

*item_instance.rb*

```
class ItemAbility < ActiveRecord::Base
    # Relationships
    belongs_to :item_type
   ...
end
```

*Ruby version:*

```
ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
```

Comment: `@item.item_abilities.build` sounds good to me, but I am not sure if this code `ItemType.item_abilities.build` makes sense. Maybe that is the reason for the error in Rails 5. I would advise you also add a tag ruby-on-rails-5 for this question.

Comment: Do you have seperate projects for your Rails 5 and Rails 4? the error seems to be coming from https://github.com/rails/protected_attributes

Comment: @gen: You're quite right. I've fixed the post accordingly.

Comment: @oreoluwa: projects are the same except for the controllers and views. Thanks for pointing out the protected_attributes gem, removing that gem from the Gemfile does fix the issue. Looks like that one is the culprit. Thanks for pointing that out ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the `protected_attributes` gem, still hanging around from the Rails 3->4 days which caused the issue above.

I posted a bug on the `protected_attributes` gem website, and they responded that the gem will not be supported in Rails 5.

If anyone else has this issue, the Rails 'proper' way to fix this can be found here: [How is attr_accessible used in Rails 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17371334/how-is-attr-accessible-used-in-rails-4) or here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html

*Thanks to @oreoluwa for pointing me in the right direction*